# Is there a way to extract json strings to multiple rows

Tags: python

Is there a way to extract json string to multiple rows as shown below

Example,

This is the dataframe I have with json string

```
Col1 Col2 
1    [{'name': 'TypeScript1', 'size': 10}, {'name': 'TypeScript2', 'size': 20}]
2    [{'name': 'TypeScript3', 'size': 30}, {'name': 'TypeScript4', 'size': 40}]
```

Is there a way to convert to below with reference key(Col1)

```
Col1 name         size
1    TypeScript1  10 
1    TypeScript2  20
2    TypeScript3  30
2    TypeScript4  40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `pandas` to iterate through the rows of the `DataFrame` and extract the `Col1` value and the values from the `Col2` JSON array. Then, use the `concat` function to concatenate DataFrames for each row.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': [1, 2],
        'Col2': [
            [{'name': 'TypeScript1', 'size': 10}, {'name': 'TypeScript2', 'size': 20}],
            [{'name': 'TypeScript3', 'size': 30}, {'name': 'TypeScript4', 'size': 40}]
        ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'name', 'size'])

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    col1 = row['Col1']
    for item in row['Col2']:
        name = item['name']
        size = item['size']
        result = pd.concat([result, pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [col1], 'name': [name], 'size': [size]})], ignore_index=True)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to transform your dataFrame (the one with nested data) to a flat structure. Try the following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2],
        'Col2': [[{'name': 'TypeScript1', 'size': 10}, {'name': 'TypeScript2', 'size': 20}],
                 [{'name': 'TypeScript3', 'size': 30}, {'name': 'TypeScript4', 'size': 40}]]})

df = df.explode('Col2').reset_index(drop=True)
df[['name', 'size']] = pd.DataFrame(df['Col2'].tolist())
df.drop(columns=['Col2'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```